# Unable to upload images

Tags: php

I was trying to upload images using the below code but it shows:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload3.php on line 57`

Here is what I have on line 57:

```
if ($file_size &amp;lt;= 0)
        HandleError('File size outside allowed lower bound'); // Validate its a MIME Images (Take note that not all MIME is the same across different browser, especially when its zip file)
```

When I remove the above line from the below code, I get `No Session was found.` on the screen and nothing else comes. Does anyone have any Idea?

```
<?php
#check for session
if (isset($_POST['PHPSESSID']))
    session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);
else if (isset($_GET['PHPSESSID']))
    session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
else
{
    HandleError('No Session was found.');
}

session_start();
// Check post_max_size (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#73762)
$POST_MAX_SIZE = ini_get('post_max_size');
$unit = strtoupper(substr($POST_MAX_SIZE, -1));
$multiplier = ($unit == 'M' ? 1048576 : ($unit == 'K' ? 1024 : ($unit == 'G' ? 1073741824 : 1)));

if ((int)$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > $multiplier*(int)$POST_MAX_SIZE && $POST_MAX_SIZE)
    HandleError('POST exceeded maximum allowed size.');

// Settings
$save_path = getcwd() . '/pictures/';  // The path were we will save the file (getcwd() may not be reliable and should be tested in your environment)
$upload_name = 'file';  // change this accordingly
$max_file_size_in_bytes = 2097152;  // 2MB in bytes
$whitelist = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'); // Allowed file extensions
$backlist = array('php', 'php3', 'php4', 'phtml','exe'); // Restrict file extensions
$valid_chars_regex = 'A-Za-z0-9_-\s '; // Characters allowed in the file name (in a Regular Expression format)

// Other variables     
$MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 260;
$file_name = '';
$file_extension = '';
$uploadErrors = array(
    0=>'There is no error, the file uploaded with success',
    1=>'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
    2=>'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
    3=>'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
    4=>'No file was uploaded',
    6=>'Missing a temporary folder'
);

// Validate the upload
if (!isset($_FILES[$upload_name]))
    HandleError('No upload found in \$_FILES for ' . $upload_name);
else if (isset($_FILES[$upload_name]['error']) && $_FILES[$upload_name]['error'] != 0)
    HandleError($uploadErrors[$_FILES[$upload_name]['error']]);
else if (!isset($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name']) || !@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name']))
    HandleError('Upload failed is_uploaded_file test.');
else if (!isset($_FILES[$upload_name]['name']))
    HandleError('File has no name.');

// Validate the file size (Warning: the largest files supported by this code is 2MB)
$file_size = @filesize($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name']);
if (!$file_size || $file_size > $max_file_size_in_bytes)
    HandleError('File exceeds the maximum allowed size');

if ($file_size &amp;lt;= 0)
    HandleError('File size outside allowed lower bound'); // Validate its a MIME Images (Take note that not all MIME is the same across different browser, especially when its zip file)
if(!eregi('image/', $_FILES[$upload_name]['type']))
    HandleError('Please upload a valid file!'); // Validate that it is an image

$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name']);
if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png' && isset($imageinfo))
    HandleError('Sorry, we only accept GIF and JPEG images');

// Validate file name (for our purposes we'll just remove invalid characters)
$file_name = preg_replace('/[^'.$valid_chars_regex.']|\.+$/i', '', strtolower(basename($_FILES[$upload_name]['name'])));
if (strlen($file_name) == 0 || strlen($file_name) > $MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH)
    HandleError('Invalid file name');

// Validate that we won't over-write an existing file
if (file_exists($save_path . $file_name))
    HandleError('File with this name already exists');

// Validate file extension
if(!in_array(end(explode('.', $file_name)), $whitelist))
    HandleError('Invalid file extension');
if(in_array(end(explode('.', $file_name)), $backlist))
    HandleError('Invalid file extension');

// Rename the file to be saved 
$file_name = md5($file_name. time());

// Verify! Upload the file
if (!@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name'], $save_path.$file_name)) 
    HandleError('File could not be saved.');

exit(0);

/* Handles the error output. */
function HandleError($message) {
    echo $message;
    exit(0);
}

?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Copying and pasting code, especially from sites that can't show source code properly, without basic knowledge of how this works, can only bring a disaster.

Answer (score 5):

it should be `<=` not `&amp;lt;=`

Comment: tried that but still the same error

Comment: @Haymi use this fix, update your script, upload it to the server, check that it has been changed on the server and check again!

Comment: my bad It now says no session was found

Comment: @relentless that wouldn't make any sense, it just looks like something converted `<=` to `&amp;lt;=`

Comment: Yup, I just looked at it again. You're right. Deleted my comment. +1

Comment: @Haymi any time you work with sessions you must have `session_start()` at the top

Comment: I have session_start() in the code. should I put it on the top?

Comment: @Haymi always at the very top, or at the very least before anything that involves the session

Comment: @DavidNguyen I put it at the top but still shows no session was found.

Comment: @DavidNguyen  I put if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) {....and put name="submited" on submit button and now it shows the html but when I try to upload it says call to undefined function HandleError..Do I really need the session part to make it work?

Comment: move your session_start to the top. delete the exit(0) before the function.